# Axis break in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I'm looking for a way to make a plot similar to the one I've sketched. [image: plot with axis break]

So far all I've found is [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/C7r9bsXbmh4), which mostly uses `Grid`. I want the second part of the plot to have a smaller interval, as shown, but when I try their technique, I get this plot:

```
Grid@{{Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], Style[Rotate["/", 0 Degree], 20], 
  Plot[Cos[2 x], {x, 6, 8}, PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1}, Axes -> {True, False}]}}
```

[image: Mathematica plot with axis break]

Notice how the scaling on the second plot changes. I'd like to keep the scaling the same between the first and second plot.

Comment: My answer in the linked duplicate candidate may be overkill for your needs, but it is possible to use it to achieve your sketch too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Grid[{{Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1}, 
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, Automatic}, AspectRatio -> Full], 
    Style["/", 20],
    Plot[Cos[2 x], {x, 6, 8}, PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1}, 
      Axes -> {True, False}, Ticks -> {{6, 7, 8}}, AspectRatio -> Full]}}, 
    ItemSize -> {{10, 1, 5}}]
```

[image]

Note that `Ticks` is used to provide a common format for the `x`-axis.

Comment: thanks, this works for me! I think a key for it is the `ItemSize` which seems to scale the different parts parts