# How to plot two time intervals of a graph simultaneously?

Tags: plotting

The graphs of my provided code look approximately like the one in the picture below. How is it possible to plot such graphs? Please help how to break the axis scale as shown. Any suggestion appreciated. Thanks a lot.
[image]

```
Subscript[C, i]=2.5*10^6
Subscript[k, e]=315
σ=1*10^-9
Subscript[S, e]=1.58*10^-5
g=2.3*10^16
Subscript[C, e]=2.1*10^4
τ=1*10^-15
a=1/τ
Subscript[w, 1]=1
Subscript[s, 1]=y/(Subscript[w, 1]*σ)
Subscript[b, 1]=g/Subscript[C, e]*(1+(Subscript[k, e]*Subscript[s, 1]^2)/g)
Subscript[Δ, 1]=Sqrt[Subscript[b, 1]^2-4*Subscript[k, e]*Subscript[s, 1]^2*g/(Subscript[C, i]*Subscript[C, e])]
Subscript[p, 11]=(-Subscript[b, 1]+Subscript[Δ, 1])/2
Subscript[p, 12]=(-Subscript[b, 1]-Subscript[Δ, 1])/2
Subscript[T, i]=(Subscript[S, e]*g)/(2*π*τ*Subscript[C, i]*Subscript[C, e])*NIntegrate[BesselJ[0,y]*Exp[-((σ^2*Subscript[s, 1]^2)/4)]*(Exp[-a*t]/((a+Subscript[p, 11])*(a+Subscript[p, 12]))+1/(Subscript[p, 11]-Subscript[p, 12])*(Exp[Subscript[p, 11]*t]/(Subscript[p, 11]+a)-Exp[Subscript[p, 12]*t]/(Subscript[p, 12]+a)))*y/(σ*Subscript[w, 1])^2,{y,0,100}]
Subscript[T, e]=Subscript[T, i]+Subscript[S, e]/(2*π*τ*Subscript[C, e])*NIntegrate[BesselJ[0,y]*Exp[-((σ^2*Subscript[s, 1]^2)/4)]*(-((a*Exp[-a*t])/((a+Subscript[p, 11])*(a+Subscript[p, 12])))+1/(Subscript[p, 11]-Subscript[p, 12])*((Subscript[p, 11]*Exp[Subscript[p, 11]*t])/(Subscript[p, 11]+a)-(Subscript[p, 12]*Exp[Subscript[p, 12]*t])/(Subscript[p, 12]+a)))*y/(σ*Subscript[w, 1])^2,{y,0,100}]
Plot[Subscript[T, e],{t,0,1*10^-14}]
Plot[Subscript[T, i],{t,0,1*10^-14}]
```

Comment: A [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239788/plotting-with-a-discontinuous-axis-using-piecewise-scalingfunctions), though without any answers; and a [related answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8241/generating-a-broken-or-snipped-axis-in-listplot/189924#189924)

Comment: Might be worth a look:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222517/how-to-break-the-x-axis-of-a-plot   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100716/axis-break-in-mathematica   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82581/switch-from-logarithmic-to-linear-scaling-partway-along-a-plots-axis

Answer (score 3):

First, I recommend that you avoid using subscripts except for display.

Since the range of your plots is only `{t, 0, 10^-14}` there are no regions where the functions are essentially constant and where a gap in the axis would be appropriate.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[Ti] = Subscript[T, i];
Format[Te] = Subscript[T, e];

Ci = 25*10^5;
ke = 315;
σ = 1*10^-9;
Se = 158*10^-7;
g = 23*10^15;
Ce = 21*10^3;
τ = 1*10^-15;
a = 1/τ;
s1[w_] = y/(w*σ);
b1[w_] = g/Ce*(1 + (ke*s1[w]^2)/g);
Δ1[w_] = Sqrt[b1[w]^2 - 4*ke*s1[w]^2*g/(Ci*Ce)];
p11[w_] = (-b1[w] + Δ1[w])/2;
p12[w_] = (-b1[w] - Δ1[w])/2;

wValues = {1, 3, 5};

Ti[t_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ] :=
 (Se*g)/(2*π*τ*Ci*Ce)*
  NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, y]*Exp[-((σ^2*s1[w]^2)/4)]*
    (Exp[-a*t]/((a + p11[w])*(a + p12[w])) +
      1/(p11[w] - p12[w])*
       (Exp[p11[w]*t]/(p11[w] + a) -
         Exp[p12[w]*t]/(p12[w] + a)))*y/(σ*w)^2,
   {y, 0, 100},
   WorkingPrecision -> 15]

Te[t_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ] := 
 Ti[t, w] + Se/(2*π*τ*Ce)*
   NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, y]*Exp[-((σ^2*s1[w]^2)/4)]*
     (-((a*Exp[-a*t])/((a + p11[w])*(a + p12[w]))) + 
       1/(p11[w] - p12[w])*
        ((p11[w]*Exp[p11[w]*t])/(p11[w] + a) - 
          (p12[w]*Exp[p12[w]*t])/(p12[w] + a)))*
     y/(σ*w)^2, 
    {y, 0, 100},
    WorkingPrecision -> 15]

Legended[
  Column[
   Plot[
      Evaluate@Table[#[t, w], {w, wValues}], 
      {t, 0, 10^-14},
      PlotRange -> All,
      Frame -> True,
      FrameLabel -> {None,
        Style[StringForm["``[t]", #], 12, Bold]},
      WorkingPrecision -> 15,
      PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashed}, {Blue, Dotted}, Black},
      ImageSize -> Medium,
      ImagePadding -> {{60, 15}, {20, 8}},
      AspectRatio ->
       If[# === Te, 1/GoldenRatio, 1/3]] & /@ {Te, Ti}],
  Placed[
   LineLegend[
    {{Red, Dashed}, {Blue, Dotted}, Black},
    StringForm["w = ``", #] & /@ wValues],
   {.6, .9}]] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: Bob, in their post, the OP shows the image of the plots they wish to emulate that stop at `10^-14` and then pick back up at `3*10^-12`, perhaps this is what they wish to replicate.

Comment: @CATrevillian - Then I believe that the OP should specify what the desired plot range is for each segment.

Answer (score 2):

Use the functions `Te` and `Ti` from Bob Hanlon's answer to get two plots for each function with desired plot ranges:

```
{xrangea, xrangeb} = {{0, 10^-14}, {10^-13, 10^-12}};

{yrange1, yrange2} = {{0, 8 10^6}, {0, 350}};

{plot1a, plot1b, plot2a, plot2b} = Quiet@Plot[
      Evaluate @ Table[#[t, w], {w, wValues}], {t, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]}, 
      PlotRange -> {All, #3}, 
      PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, Scaled[.05]}, Axes -> False, 
      Frame -> True,
      FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic},
        {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][#, #2, 3] &, Automatic}}, 
      FrameLabel -> {None, #4}, WorkingPrecision -> 15, 
      PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashed}, {Blue, Dotted}, Black},
      PlotLegends -> ({#, #4} /. {{_, None} | {Ti, _} -> None, {Te, _} -> 
        Placed[PromptForm[w , #] & /@ wValues, {.7, .8}]})] & @@@ 
   (Tuples[{{Te, Ti}, Thread[{{xrangea, xrangeb}, {lbl, None}}]}] /. 
    {a_, {b_, c_}} :> {a, b, a /. {Te -> yrange1, Ti -> yrange2}, 
      c /. lbl -> Style[a[t], 12, Bold]});
```

and combine the four plots using Lukas Lang's [ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/)

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{{plot1a, plot1b}, {plot2a, plot2b}}, 
 "MergeAxes" -> {"Cut", False}, Spacings -> {20, 30}, 
 ImageSize -> 700, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 ItemSize -> {{{Scaled}, Scaled[.005]}, {700, 300}}]
```

[image]